# Ruby on Rails: check_box_tag - default if nothing selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, default

I have an app where a user can enter a project into a database.

There is an option where they can select a number of different technologies for their project. At the moment, the app flags up an error if the user doesn't select at least 1 technology.

I am wanting to change this so that if they don't select a technology, it automatically goes down as "other" instead.

**Here is my project controller actions, new and create:**

```
def new
    @project = Project.new
        @technol = Technol.new(params[:tech])

        @all_technols = Technol.order('tech ASC') 
        @all_technols = Technol.all
        tech_ids = params[:technols][:id].reject(&:blank?) unless params[:technols].nil?


        @project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
  end



def create  
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])
        @project.client = params[:new_client] unless params[:new_client].blank?
        @project.industry = params[:new_industry] unless params[:new_industry].blank?
        @project.business_div = params[:new_business_div] unless params[:new_business_div].blank?


if !params[:technols].nil?

            params[:technols][:id].each do |tech|


                if !tech.empty?

                    @project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build(:technol_id => tech) 
                    end
            end

end
```

**Here is the new view for the technology field**

```
<ul> 


<% @all_technols.each do |technol| %> 



<li class="split"> 
<%= check_box_tag "project[technol_ids][]", technol.id,  @project.technols.include?(technol) %> 
<%= technol.tech %> 
</li> 

<% end %>
</ul>
```

The technology ID for "other" in the technols table is "18". So is there a way to say that if no technology is chosen, then `:technol_id => ["18"]`.

I'm still new to rails, so please remember this when trying to help. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices.

First, add an hidden input to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="project[technol_ids][]" value="18" />
```

Second, update params in controller#action:

```
def create
  ...
  technol_ids = params[:technol_ids].blank? ? [18] : params[:technol_ids]
  technol_ids.each do |id|
  ...
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="project[technol_ids][]" value="18" />` works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: I just think of one thing: with hidden input, 18 will be added to all projects. Maybe this is not what you want. You'd better try the second  solution.

Comment: I noticed that after posting. Found another solution. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to write a migration and set a default value of the column as follow

```
add_column :users, :technology, :string, :default => "other"
```

So even if the user will not select any value default will be true not nil

Comment: I have added a migration `change_column :projecttechnols, :technol_id, :integer, :default => 18`. This doesn't seem to save a technology when I enter a new project